# How to clean up poorly HTML in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, html, parsing

I have an asp web page that is created run time. It has a static template but the elements of page and its information created based on user inputs in other pages of application.
And user can insert data in html format too. the problem is happen when user input data in html format but he/she forgets to close html tags or so on.
It doesn't cause crash in application, but browser will be confuse when it wants to display a page. 
I need to clean up or parse user input in the run time when page is created. 
Is any one knows how to do this? Is there any library or function for ASP.net?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to read the HTML in and then write it out, cleaned up.

Sample usage (do not forget using HtmlAgilityPack namespace)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Tidy up a partial html string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="html">Html string to tidy.</param>
    /// <returns>A cleaned html string.</returns>
    /// <remarks>If <paramref name="html" /> contains a body tag, 
    /// it returns only first body contents.</remarks>
    public static string TidyPartial(string html)
    {
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
        // If you wish it to be xhtml like (does not suffice to 
        // enforce w3c xhtml validity).
        doc.OptionOutputAsXml = true;
        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        var body = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
        var cleanedHtml = (body != null) ? 
            body.InnerHtml : doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
        return cleanedHtml;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Tidy.net to format the HTML correctly.[tidy.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tidynet/)

```
var document = new Tidy();
var messageCollection = new TidyMessageCollection();
document.Options.DocType = DocType.Omit;
document.Options.Xhtml = true;
document.Options.CharEncoding = CharEncoding.UTF8;
document.Options.LogicalEmphasis = true;
document.Options.MakeClean = false;
document.Options.QuoteNbsp = false;
document.Options.SmartIndent = false;
document.Options.IndentContent = false;
document.Options.TidyMark = false;
document.Options.DropFontTags = false;
document.Options.QuoteAmpersand = true;
document.Options.DropEmptyParas = true;
using (var input = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var output = new MemoryStream())
    {
        byte[] array = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlResult);
        input.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
        input.Position = 0;
        document.Parse(input, output, messageCollection);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(output.ToArray());
    }
}
```

you need to be careful of cross side scripting when users can add html to pages.
Have a look at this post for [Sanitising HTML with C# and Tidy](http://www.robertbeal.com/37/sanitising-html)